# docker containers nginx + radicale gives bad gateway

Tags: python, docker, nginx, webserver

I try to run radicale (python caldav server) on Docker with a nginx reverse proxy, aiming to provide SSL encryption but I struggle with a 502 Bad Gateway.

Based on various codes, I created this radicale container which run ok but when I link it to
the reverse proxy I get the bad gateway error.

I am running my code with `docker-compose up --build`.

My docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  reverseproxy:
    container_name: nginxrp
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/html:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx/core.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./nginx/logs:/var/log/nginx/
    links:
      - radicale

  
  radicale:
    container_name: radicale
    build:
      context: .
    # ports:
    #   - "127.0.0.1:5232:5656"
    volumes:
      - ./radicale/config:/etc/radicale/config.txt
      - ./radicale/data:/var/lib/radicale/
```

My radicale config (server run great on localhost:5232 when I do the port mapping) :

```
[server]
hosts = 0.0.0.0:5656
```

My nginx reverseproxy config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name rad.local;

     error_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.error_log info;

    location / {
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html;
    }

    location /calendar {
        root /var/www/html;
        index calendar.html;
    }

    location /radicale/ { 
        proxy_pass        http://radicale; # docker service name
        proxy_set_header  X-Script-Name /radicale;
        proxy_pass_header Authorization;
        proxy_set_header            Host $host;
        proxy_set_header            X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_http_version          1.1;
        proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-Proto http;
        proxy_redirect              http:// $scheme://;

    }
}
```

also my Dockerfile for the custom radicale image :

```
FROM alpine:3.17.3

ARG VERSION
ENV VERSION ${VERSION:-3.1.8}

ARG BUILD_UID
ENV BUILD_UID ${BUILD_UID:-2999}

ARG BUILD_GID
ENV BUILD_GID ${BUILD_GID:-2999}

ARG TAKE_FILE_OWNERSHIP
ENV TAKE_FILE_OWNERSHIP ${TAKE_FILE_OWNERSHIP:-true}

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual=build-dependencies \
        gcc \
        musl-dev \
        libffi-dev \
        python3-dev \
    && apk add --no-cache \
        curl \
        git \
        openssh \
        shadow \
        su-exec \
        tzdata \
        wget \
        python3 \
        py3-tz \
        py3-pip \
    && python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip \
    && python3 -m pip install radicale==$VERSION passlib[bcrypt] \
    && apk del --purge build-dependencies \
    && addgroup -g $BUILD_GID radicale \
    && adduser -D -s /bin/false -H -u $BUILD_UID -G radicale radicale \
    && mkdir -p /config /data \
    && chmod -R 770 /data \
    && chown -R radicale:radicale /data \
    && rm -fr /root/.cache

# COPY ./radicale/config /config/config

# HEALTHCHECK --interval=30s --retries=3 CMD curl --fail http://localhost:5656 || exit 1
VOLUME ./radicale/data /data
EXPOSE 5656

COPY ./radicale/users.txt /etc/radicale/users

COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 777 /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["radicale", "--config", "/etc/radicale/config.txt"]
```

I think it may be a container networking problem/port mapping?

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated!